# Ubuntu installation on old laptop : This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU

Tags: 14.04, boot, drivers, system-installation, kernel

I am using a mac to create a bootable usb

**Additional Bug report :** While using UNetbootin it did not show any of my files in any folders instead i have to search the particular file

**Laptop model number : Asus ee pc 1015cx-blk024w**

I tried changing the bios settings and to enable intel VT-x/AMD-V but there is no such option

Can anybody tell me a workaround?

*Also is this distribution is not suitable for this laptop please tell me the list of distros that will work on this laptop*

Comment: Sounds like you're using the 64bit ISO file to make your boot disk. Based on the error you're getting,  you'll need the 32bit ISO file. The Asus EeePC's were mostly 32bit.

Comment: The output in the title says that you should download another iso file with a 32-bit version of Ubuntu (or Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu). Such iso files have the string 'i386' in the file name, for example **lubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-i386.iso**. You find the current iso files via this link, http://releases.ubuntu.com/

Comment: is there a ubuntu 32 but? can i get a link? and how different are l, x, or k ubuntus from the native @sudodus

Comment: http://releases.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Lubuntu has an ultra-light desktop environment, Ubuntu MATE and Xubuntu have medium light  desktop environments, and will probably work better in your eeePC compared to standard Ubuntu and Kubuntu. See this link (and links from it) for more details, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you downloaded a 64-bit image, but your laptop only has a 32-bit CPU. Seeing as this is an older computer, I would recommend that you try Xubuntu 32-bit.

Comment: is there a ubuntu 32 bit? can you give me a link for that

Comment: @IshanSrivastava http://mirror.pnl.gov/releases/xenial/ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-i386.iso